# Jenkins "Keep this build forever" button is missing for other users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I can see as an admin but other users who are not admin role they can't see this button. We have security enabled with access control through LDAP and authorization is Role Base strategy.
I can't find any option in Role base strategy that can enable it.

Any help on how can I enable it for other users?

Answer (score 18):

We use Matrix-based security.

In order for the "Keep this build forever" option to show up for our users, we had to enable "Update" permisson under the "Run" section.